# Multiple "style" attributes in a "span" tag: what's supposed to happen?

Tags: html

Consider the following HTML fragment with two `style` attributes:

```
<span style="color:blue" style="font-style:italic">Test</span>
```

In Opera 12.16 and Chrome 40, it shows up as blue non-italic text, while Internet Explorer 9 shows blue italic text.  What, if anything, does the standard say is supposed to show up?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In HTML, SGML and [XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088971/how-to-handle-duplicate-attribute-names-and-hexadecimal-values), <sup>(1)</sup> attributes cannot be repeated, and should only be defined in an element *once*.

So your example:

```
<span style="color:blue" style="font-style:italic">Test</span>
```

is *non-conformant* to the HTML standard, and will result in undefined behaviour, which explains why different browsers are rendering it differently.

---

Since there is no defined way to interpret this, browsers can interpret it however they want and merge them, or ignore them as they wish.

<sup>(1): Every article I can find states that attributes are "key/value" pairs or "attribute-value" pairs, heavily implying the keys must be unique. [The best source I can find states](http://www.tei-c.org/Vault/P4/doc/html/SG.html#index-div3-id683252):</sup>

> <sup>Attribute names (id and status in this example) are subject to the same restrictions as other names in XML; they need not be unique across the whole DTD, however, but only *within the list of attributes for a given element*. <sup>*(Emphasis mine.)*</sup></sup>

Comment: How about add your style by id or class? When onload.
@Skatox I want to add comment sorry about my mistake :(

Comment: @lv0gun9 Thats irrelevant to the question at hand. The question wasn't about how to add a class, it was about how different browsers treat duplicate attributes.

Answer (score 53):

Separate your rules with a semi colon in a single declaration:

`<span style="color:blue;font-style:italic">Test</span>`

Comment: I know how I'm *supposed* to do it; what I want to know is what is supposed to happen if I don't (or in my specific case, what happens if an automated HTML generator messes up).

Comment: ah my bad, I misunderstood the question :)

Comment: this might not answer the OP's question but I found it really useful to have on this same Q&A page

Comment: Well it helped me! Thanks!