# select same child node from openxml sql stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, openxml

I have one XML String as below :

```
<XML>
   <ProductDetail>
        <Barcode>170604658</Barcode>
       <PropertyDetail>
             <PropertyKey>Size</PropertyKey>
             <PropertyValue>XXL</PropertyValue>
             <PropertyKey>ProdTaxType</PropertyKey>
             <PropertyValue>5%</PropertyValue>
       </PropertyDetail>
   </ProductDetail>
</XML>
```

i m reading the XML Data via below small query in sp:

```
 SELECT  *
   FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'XML/ProductDetail/PropertyDetail', 2) WITH
   (
            PropertyKey VARCHAR(200) ,
            PropertyValue VARCHAR(200) 
   )XML
```

BUT , FOR above i m getting one row data as below :

```
PropertyKey PropertyValue
    Size    XXL
```

BUT , as per XML Defined i want to get the data as per below :

```
PropertyKey     PropertyValue
 Size              XXL
 ProdTaxType       5%
```

FOR the same chile node name i am getting only one record from xml string. So, please suggest in above sp.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Most products have their own versions of stored procedures.)

Comment: MS SQL SERVER...

Comment: Aren't you missing calling `EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc;` in your sample? 
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your XML is not formed well, it should be like this:

```
DECLARE @hdoc varchar(max) = '<XML>
      <ProductDetail>
        <Barcode>150604658</Barcode>
       <PropertyDetail>
                     <PropertyKey>Size</PropertyKey>
                     <PropertyValue>XXL</PropertyValue>
       </PropertyDetail>
       <PropertyDetail>
                    <PropertyKey>ProdTaxType</PropertyKey>
                    <PropertyValue>5%</PropertyValue>
       </PropertyDetail>
   </ProductDetail>
</XML>'
```

In your example the `PropertyDetail` has duplicate attributes.

It could be also re-written like this:

```
DECLARE @hdoc varchar(max) = '<XML>
      <ProductDetail Barcode="150604658">
       <PropertyDetail PropertyKey="Size" PropertyValue="XXL" />
       <PropertyDetail PropertyKey="ProdTaxType" PropertyValue="5%" />
     </ProductDetail>
</XML>'
```

Now you would not think of writing:

```
<PropertyDetail PropertyKey="Size" PropertyValue="XXL" 
                PropertyKey="ProdTaxType" PropertyValue="5%" />
```

but the meaning is the same as the XML you have - [and duplicate attributes are not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10089029/2224701).